# Save captured video via Android intent to specific directory and file name

Tags: android, android-intent, video, media

I am able create and start an intent to capture a video. But how can I set the file name and save it to a specific directory?

Here's what I have so far:

```
videoPath = "/X1," + num1 +
             ",Y1," + num2 +
             ",X2," + num3 +
             ",Y2," + num4 +
             ",A," + num5 +
             ",G," + num6 +
             ",la," + num7 +
             ",lo," + num8+ ".mp4";

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoPath);
startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_INTENT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I set the file name and save it to a specific directory?

You are setting the filename. It is most of what you have in `videoPath`.

However:

1. Your `videoPath` does not specify a directory, other than an invalid leading slash. Use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` to get a likely `File` object for the directory, then create a new `File` object pointing to the actual file you want to use.
2. I am not sure if commas will work well in filenames here.
3. `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is a `Uri`, not a `String` or a `File`. Use `Uri.fromFile()` to convert your `File` to a `Uri`.